# Derivative of Integral $f(t-x) dt$

Tags: integration, derivatives

I was wondering about the following derivative of the following integral:

$F(x) = \int_0^x{f(t-x) dt}$

So: $F'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x{f(t-x) dt}$

What I did is:

$F'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x{f(t-x) dt} $

$= \frac{d}{dx} F(t-x)\vert_0^x $

$= \frac{d}{dx} (F(x-x) - F(0-x)) $

$= \frac{d}{dx}(F(0) - (F(-x)) $

$= f(-x)$

However I am not so sure about this. Is this going into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Better alternative:

$$\int ^x _0 f(t-x)=\int^x_0f((x-t)-x) \tag{1}$$ 
$$ Note: \int^a_bf(x)=\int^a_bf(a+b-x)$$

Continue $(1)$

$$F(x)=\int ^x_0f(-t)$$

rest You know Newton Leibeneze rule

Comment: Is it supposed to say "-(1)"? You are trying to number the equation, right? Now it just looks like you're subtracting $1$.

Comment: @Lovsovs Just numbering the equation.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I am getting the same result. So what I have in the question is correct I think.

Comment: I edited your answer accordingly.